# how to use "position" in insert() in python list

Tags: python

I am trying basics of list() in python, and apart from expend(), in insert(), it says it can insert an element at given position.

If my list has 3 elements and I try to insert at 7th position it totally inserts it, I can't understand how does it work ? is there 4th and 5th position in between and if yes what is stored there? for example below the length of a_list is 3, because it has 3 elements then how does position matter?

```
>>a_list = ['1', '2']
>>a_list.insert( 7, 'a')
>>print (a_list)
>>print (len(a_list))
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: One way to find out is to try!

Comment: if you are trying to insert in position 3 and there is already some element in position 3, your you element is going to be in index 3 and the other moved to position 4,5, etc. if you wan introduce in index 10 but your list has only 5 number your new value will be introduced at the end of the list so it will not be in index 10

Comment: As the list is a sequential mutable data type Item will insert in the
next index position if the given index is invalid. the element is inserted into next consecutive index of the list. there is no 4th and 5th position in between 
    a_list = ['1', '2']
    a_list.insert( 7, 'a') #as index is invalid item will insert into len(a_list)+1 index 
    print (a_list) # ['1','2','a']
    print (len(a_list)) # 3
You can check that there is no index of 4 and 5 as you are thinking.
       print (a_list[4]) #list index out of range 
       print (a_list[5]) #list index out of range

Answer (score -1):

If you use insert with a index above the size of your array it will be stored in the last position +1 of your array and not the one that you provided.

In your example you use **a_list.insert( 7, 'a')** it will add the element 'a' to the position a_list[2]

However if you want to pre initialize an array of n elements do something like this

```
a_list = [None] * 8
```

It will create an array with len == 8 with all values store with *None*